# How to find out the location of the httpd.conf configuration file controlling the behavior of the python 2.7 httpserver module.?

Tags: python-2.7, httpd.conf, simplehttpserver

I am running python -m httpserver on Macintosh OS X.

Here's the Python 2.7 code implementing the httpserver:

```
import CGIHTTPServer
import BaseHTTPServer

class Handler(CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    cgi_directories = ["/cgi"]

PORT = 9999

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

When I type at the web browser http://localhost:9999/adder.html, I wish to find out the location of the httpd.conf configuration file controlling the behavior of the python 2.7 httpserver module.

There is also an apache24 httpd daemon process running simultaneously. I would guess that they are both using different httpd.conf files in different locations. The httpd.conf file corresponding to the apache24 httpd daemon process is frozen in root read onlypermission which I cannot change so that I make the python 2.7 cgi script executable through the auspices of the cgi module as shown below in the excerpt from this URL, 
[Python script does not run through CGI on Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727053/python-script-does-not-run-through-cgi-on-apache2) because Lesley University's information technology specialists have blocked users like myself from running operating system command as sudo .

Without the cgi_module, even code that is chmod +x will not be executable, so uncomment this line:

## LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so

And change your Directory to look like this (mine works like this):

AllowOverride None
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    Options ExecCGI 
    AddHandler cgi-script .py

Without this change to the responsible httpd.conf file, I get the following
nonsensical message:

Opening adder.cgi , You have chosen to open adder.gui which is a binary file(5.0KB) from httpd://localhost.9999. Would you like to save this file? Cancel or Save

instead of seeing adder.cgi launch a child process.

I am hypothesizing that the python 2.7 httpserver module can reference a non-default httpd.conf in  subdirectory relative to the current working directory.

Please let me know if you need more data from me. Thank you for looking at this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618084/python-cgihttpserver-default-directories

Comment: I will test these helpful hints this morning and report back my findings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618084/python-cgihttpserver-default-directories,  https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html and  http://tasdikrahman.me/2015/10/20/Running-CGI-Scripts-with-CGIHTTPServer/

Answer (score 0):

After reading the ServerFault article https://serverfault.com/questions/168132/setting-up-cgihttpserver-on-osx titled "Setting up CGIHTTPServer on OSX", my Python 2.7 CGI script using /usr/bin/env python was successfully served on a desktop MacIntosh OS X running CGIHTTPServer when I browsed to http://127.0.0.1:8000/WWW/test.py.

Apparently the CGIHTTPServer.py class does not read from the Apache Web server configuration file httpd.conf. Instead the information contained in httpd.conf is "baked into" the CGIHTTPServer.py class source code.

Comment: Why is launching a python child process on Windows way slower than on macintosh os x?